# Python error. ImportError: No module named feature_format

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I am learning Regression from the Udacity course `"Intro to Machine Learning"` and I am going through the mini-project in it.

I copied the code of the project, wrote the regression part, as a part of code and tried running it on Jupyter Notebook in Python 2. Unfortunately, I got the following error.

```
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-8-433cee6c5e25> in <module>()
         15 import pickle
         16 sys.path.append("../tools/")
    ---> 17 from feature_format import featureFormat, targetFeatureSplit
         18 dictionary = pickle.load( open("../final_project/final_project_dataset_modified.pkl", "r") )
         19 

    ImportError: No module named feature_format
```

The code on which I am working is as follows:
Loads up/formats a modified version of the datasetn(why modified?  we've removed some trouble pointsnthat you'll find yourself in the outliers mini-project).nDraws a little scatterplot of the training/testing datanYou fill in the regression code where indicated:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import sys
    import pickle
    sys.path.append("../tools/")
    from feature_format import featureFormat, targetFeatureSplit
    dictionary = pickle.load( open("../final_project/final_project_dataset_modified.pkl", "r") )

    ### list the features you want to look at--first item in the 
    ### list will be the "target" feature
    features_list = ["bonus", "salary"]
    data = featureFormat( dictionary, features_list, remove_any_zeroes=True)
    target, features = targetFeatureSplit( data )

    ### training-testing split needed in regression, just like classification
    from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
    feature_train, feature_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(features, target, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)
    train_color = "b"
    test_color = "r"


    ### Your regression goes here!
    ### Please name it reg, so that the plotting code below picks it up and 
    ### plots it correctly. Don't forget to change the test_color above from "b" to
    ### "r" to differentiate training points from test points.
    from sklearn import linear_model
    reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    reg.fit(feature_train,target_train)


    ### draw the scatterplot, with color-coded training and testing points
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    for feature, target in zip(feature_test, target_test):
        plt.scatter( feature, target, color=test_color ) 
    for feature, target in zip(feature_train, target_train):
        plt.scatter( feature, target, color=train_color ) 

    ### labels for the legend
    plt.scatter(feature_test[0], target_test[0], color=test_color, label="test")
    plt.scatter(feature_test[0], target_test[0], color=train_color, label="train")

    ### draw the regression line, once it's coded
    try:
        plt.plot( feature_test, reg.predict(feature_test) )
    except NameError:
        pass
    plt.xlabel(features_list[1])
    plt.ylabel(features_list[0])
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I had to create a virtual environment in anaconda for this course, specifically for python 2.7 and installed other programs with package manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cause

`ImportError: No module named feature_format` tells that there is no module named `feature_format`.

the module is already defined in the repository you are using at `ud120-projects/tools/feature_format.py`.

### Solution 1

the path to `feature_format` module is declared in `k_means_cluster.py` line number 3. as an argument passed to `sys.path.append`.

change path from relative to absolute path e.g. `sys.path.append("ud120-projects/tools/")`.

### Solution 2

Everything is alright do this simple trick.
clone the GitHub repository

```
git clone https://github.com/udacity/ud120-projects.git
```

go to directory `ud120-projects/k_means/` with

```
cd ud120-projects/k_means/
```

and then the python script with python2

```sh
python k_means_cluster.py
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install feature_format
```

before you import feature_format. This "should" install it.